# why custom tasks on windows scheduler do not execute..?

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-3.0, windows-task-scheduler

I tried creating a task in windows task scheduler, where i put trigger on some specific time. but even when time passes task is not triggered.
my task always shows me status "Ready", even at anticipated time is shows "Ready" not "Running" why is it so, if there is any way of doing it with powershell let me know.

i have created scheduled tasks with help of powershell commandlet on remote computer.

```
    $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $cr            
    Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { $start = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(1).ToString("HH:mm:ss")

   [string]$Result = schtasks /create /tn "bittry1" /tr" $PSHome\powershell.exe Start-BitsTransfer -Source D:\a.exe -Destination C:\ -Asynchronous " /sc once /st $start /ru "Administrator" /rp "passw0rd@12"
   $Result
   }
```

Comment: Does the create task have the right time and configuraiton details that you set when you go to view it? Is it enabled? Maybe you need `/ENABLE` on the end?

Comment: @Matt.. it is enabled already..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather you're trying to call `Powershell.exe` and run `Start-BitsTransfer -Source D:\a.exe -Destination C:\ -Asynchronous` with it?

If this is the case you need to use the `-command` argument. Also I would recommend just calling `Powershell` rather than `$PSHome\Powershell.exe`.

Lastly rather than creating a task to run in a minute, you could create it and force it to run immediately.

```
   $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $cr            
   Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
       [string]$Result = schtasks /create /tn "bittry1" /tr "powershell -command {Start-BitsTransfer -Source D:\a.exe -Destination C:\ -Asynchronous} " /sc once /SD "01/01/2000" /ST "00:00:00" /ru "Administrator" /rp "passw0rd@12"
       $Result += schtasks /run /tn "bittry1"
       $Result
   }
```

You could likely get away with your +1 minute schedule, I think fixing the other bits should let it work but I find this to be a bit more rigid.

If that doesn't fix it you should try manually creating the task exactly the same and see if it runs then.